# Is it possible to add JAR from bin folder of other project lib

Tags: android, jar, runtime

Is it possible to add a JAR file from the bin folder of a library project in the same workspace programatically at run time. I can do it manually.

screenshot : [image]

[image]

Comment: why? contents in bin is generated while compiling the project. What is so special about your jar? where is coming from?

Comment: i need JAR file of the project other than the same one from bin folder.. is there any way

Comment: project > export > jar

Comment: what i need is jars from internal folders. and need it from bin folder. The above images is the manual way of getting it. is there any way to do it programatically..

Comment: I still have no idea what is you are actually looking for  ( i get that u need jar from bin folder).Like I said bin is a output folder it is generated from your source. Instead catching something from generated output, you might what to consider adding a reference to project or add a android lib project. For your answer It could be possible by inserting some custom builder in the eclipse build steps. I dnt use eclipse anymore, but I am pretty sure it is possible using custom extension to eclipse. But I am 90% sure that is not what you want.

Comment: i have a main project associated with 4 sub libraries. these sub libraries depends on main project. so inside sub libraries i added the main project as referenced project. Also my main project need to call methods of sub libraries. but, du to he cycle dependency error i need to add jar files of sub librarie's back to main project. remember my build is not for one time. its a continuous process. so i cant manually make JARs after each change in my projects.. trying dynamic referencing a way possible

Comment: You shouldn't make circular dependencies

Comment: yes i know, but in my case , what i trying to do is dynamic referencing..